# How can I authorise second Html page in App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am building a web app for work on App Script that renders different Html views for certain tasks. It is published as a private app and anyone from our domain should have access.

The users can access the main app page no problem, which is 'MantraCMS' from the code pasted below. When they try to click on the link for 'equipment' there is an error message saying that they do not have permission to run the app. I do not have this problem as the project owner.

It has me stuck, but I am assuming that it is connected to the `parameters` in the `function doGet()`

Here is the code:

```
function doGet(e) {
  
  if (e.parameters.v == 'equipment'){
  return loadEquipment();
} else {
  return loadSwirly()
}
};


function loadSwirly() {

   
   var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('MantraCMS');
  
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
   var ws = ss.getSheetByName('Options');
   var list = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getRange('A1').getDataRegion().getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  
  
   tmp.list = list.map(function(r){return r[0];});
   return tmp.evaluate();

};

function loadEquipment(){

   var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('equipment');
  
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
   var ws = ss.getSheetByName('equipment');
   var list = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getRange('A1').getDataRegion().getLastRow(), 10).getValues();
  
  
   tmp.list = list.map(function(r){return r[0];});
   return tmp.evaluate();


};
```

Here is the relevant HTML code requested. I am using a Materialize navbar:

```
<nav>
                        <div class="nav-wrapper indigo darken-4">
                            <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Swirly</a>
                            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                                <li>
                                    <a
                                        href="https://script.google.com/a/'DOMAIN'/macros/s/'SCRIPT_ID'/dev?v=cms"
                                        >Projects</a
                                    >
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a
                                        href="https://script.google.com/a/'DOMAIN'/macros/s/'SCRIPT_ID'/dev?v=equipment"
                                        >Equipment</a
                                    >
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="collapsible.html">Orders</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </nav>
```

Also the problem is the same whether it is executed as me or " user accessing web app"

I have removed the script id and domain from the html, but they are the same for both links. The orders link is a section I have not started working on yet, hence why the href is different.

Has anyone seen this kind of problem before?

Many thanks.

Comment: Who is the user executing the app, is it you or every user? What did you set it to when publishing? When you say "click on equipment" you are not showing us that code. Please show all the necessary and minimal code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Provide [mcve]. Minimal, but complete. I specifically want to see your html  head, base target parts. Also why are you using `/dev`?

Comment: @TheMaster I didn't notice the /dev part of the url to be honest. I obviusly didn't change between testing and publishing. That will likely explain!

Comment: Consider adding a answer. See [answer]